# Can not install Ubuntu Server v23.04 guest on macOS host machine in virtual box

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-server

I tried to set up Ubuntu Server v.23.04 guest machine for SSH remote access in my virtual environment using Virtual Box v. 7.0 hosted on macOS Monterey 12.6.5 . To my surprise I receive some errors.
Below I paste error.

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: no working init found. Try passing init= option to Kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.
```

I have logs. Let me know what if there is something needed for Troubleshooting.

Comment: It's not clear to me what "tried to set up" means and when this error occurred. While booting the setup/live medium? Or while booting the installed system? If after installing, please describe in as much detail as possible how exactly you installed and which virtual hardware you chose for the VM.

Comment: After initial on boot screen and selecting Try to install from medium/drive. So Yes while booting on start during installation.

Comment: Maybe your download got corrupted. Download again and [verify the downloaded file](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu).

Comment: I followed steps in guide. As it turns out the command in last section produce no output. This will mean that iso file is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a verification of iso file with this tutorial: [link](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview)
It turns out that iso image I got is erroneous somehow.
Last command produce no output which is bad

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).